# Layout in VCL - where can I find it

Tags: c++, c++builder, firemonkey, vcl

Where are layout managers (like Qt's grid layout etc) in Borland's VCL/FireMonkey? I've tried to look for them but they are well hidden, or God forbid non-existent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you're searching for this?

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/FMX.Layouts

Comment: yes, thank you, but those are only relevant to FireMonkey, is there anything with relation to layouts and VCL?

Comment: The last version I used was 2007 and - AFAIK - there were none such controls. You're left with panels/groupbox and anchors. The wiki I linked doesn't give much hope about the current version either: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE2/en/VCL_Components_Categories_Index

Comment: Consider the fact, that pure VCL is just a wrapper over WinAPI's windows (such as Windows Forms are). These do not support advanced control positioning - only by position, size and anchor. You may seek 3rd party controls though - check Torry (http://www.torry.net)

Comment: thank you for your answer. Bit dissapointing. I've tried this new release and unfortunately it looks quite poorly compared to Qt - which I'm going to stay with. And I really had such high hopes for this XE3 product. Pity.

Comment: I was going to accept your answer anyway. Just waited for your last reply. Thanks.

Comment: By the way, are you forced to use VCL (eg. in work)? If you're writing only home projects, consider switching to C++/C#. Windows Forms are equally easy to use as VCL and in fact even a little faster compared to the first one. If you have large codebase in Delphi, you can always convert it to DLL and use freely in C# application by P/Invoke. Performance-critical parts can be written in C++, too. I did such programming platform switch some time ago and I don't regret it :)

Comment: I was simply trying to compare XE3 and Qt (and perhaps switch from Qt to XE3). Unfortunately there is simply no comparison - XE3 looks like in beta stage and I remember this interface I believe 15 years ago! Nothing changed - this is simply bad and I am more than happy to stay with Qt. The main reason I was looking at XE3 is bcc64 clang based compiler. But I believe there are some talks about clang being the default compiler for Qt, so for me Qt is the right choice.